# MapRoute or MapHttpRoute in MVC WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

Since WebApi rout mapping can be done by MapHttpRoute:

```
            myConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Do I also need to map routs using MapRoute like this:

```
            RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

- *First Question:* Correct me if I'm wrong. I reckon **MapRoute** is just to support MVC pages like help page and so on...so if I don't
  have any MVC page for my Api, Do I still need to implement
  **routes.MapRoute** part?
- *Second Question:* If I need to add any mvc page to my Api(i.e. help page) can it be done by **MapHttpRoute**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First question**

if you dont use MVC you dont need **MapRoute**

**Second question**

No. MapHttpRoute will only target action methods inside the classes derived  from [ApiController](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx) (or implementations of IHttpController but that is an advance scenario most of the time you will derive from ApiController).

On the other hand, looking at the namespace is intuitive enough.

`MapRoute` is a method of the class RouteCollectionExtensions which is in  System.Web.Mvc namespace see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470521(v=vs.118).aspx) for more info

and

`MapHttpRoute` is a method of the class HttpRouteCollectionExtensions which is in  System.Web.Http namespace see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh835153(v=VS.118).aspx) for more info

Here the System.Web.Http is related with WebAPI.

Comment: thanks! so basically as long as there is no Controller derived from System.Web.Mvc.Controller in the project, MapHttpRoute is enough. Once I need a MVC page and add a Controller derived from System.Web.Mvc.Controller I should implement MapRoute part.